dnsmasq container is not accessible from outside
I have a CentOS 7 VPS running multiple services in Docker containers. All services are exposed to 127.0.0.1 and accessed via ZeroTier. I route connections from the ZeroTier (ZT) interface to localhost to access my services using <zt_server_ip>:<service_port>:
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.ztyxa6sxte.route_localnet=1
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i ztyxa6sxte -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1

This works perfectly for all services — except for dnsmasq. I'm using the jpillora/dnsmasq image with a simple web UI. My docker-compose.yml:
services:
  dns:
    container_name: dns
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: jpillora/dnsmasq
    volumes:
      - /etc/dnsmasq/dnsmasq.conf:/etc/dnsmasq.conf
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:53:53"
      - "127.0.0.1:53:53/udp"
      - "127.0.0.1:5380:8080"
    environment:
      - HTTP_USER=<user>
      - HTTP_PASS=<pass>

Despite having the same port configuration as other services, neither dnsmasq (port 53) nor its Web UI (port 5380) is accessible via the ZT interface — only locally from the VPS.
I've tried:

other images - no change
exposing to 0.0.0.0 and connecting via the VPS's public IP - same
netstat shows ports are bound to the correct IP and in the "listen" state
SELinux and firewalld are disabled
iptables policy is ACCEPT, I can provide the output if needed.
SSH reverse tunnel for port 5380 worked, I could access localhost:5380 from my PC.

I feel like I’m missing something obvious but can’t figure it out. I need a fresh perspective, please help me break out of this loop

WebUI Issue
While monitoring the ZT interface on my server with tcpdump, I noticed that requests to the WebUI on port 5380 were going through fine, and responses were being sent back. The problem turned out to be related to Basic Auth. I was testing accessibility with Chrome, which no longer supports Basic Auth.
What confused me was that the reverse tunnel worked and showed the login dialog. My guess is that Chrome allows Basic Auth when accessing localhost, but ignores it for external addresses. Switching to another browser resolved the issue — WebUI works fine everywhere else.
DNS Issue
When I first set this up and tested <my.domain> in a browser, I got no response. After that, I only tested using nslookup on my Windows PC. The catch here is that ZeroTier uses NRPT (Name Resolution Policy Table) for DNS on Windows, but nslookup doesn’t respect it.
I joined the ZT network from my phone, and the DNS worked perfectly. Then, I tested again from the browser on my PC, and it worked there too.
No changes were made to the configuration during this time, but the server was rebooted once, maybe that helped.
And DNS on PC stopped resolving again. Found the problem. It's outline VPN. When I connected to outline - it's not resolving with my DNS.
